# How is mechanical energy conserved when a ball is thrown?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy

Suppose someone is holding a ball at some height,the ball will have some potential energy and 0 kinetic energy then, if the ball is thrown both the potential energy and kinetic energy will increase then how will the mechanical energy be conserved?
Since  potential energy + kinetic energy = constant
According to the law of conservation of energy .

Comment: When you throw the ball you're adding mechanical energy to the system. This energy comes from the chemical energy stored in your muscles. First it gets turned into kinetic energy, which then turns gradually into potential energy as Young Kindaichi says.

Comment: Gravitational PE is defined as mgh, when the ball is thrown the height decreases so does the PE while KE is 1/2mv^2 ,as the object falls down its kinetic energy increases as it is under constant acceleration( due to the force of gravity)

Comment: @KristofferSjöö  What if the ball keeps speeding up and never slows down ?

Comment: That means magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you are on the roof which is above height $h$ from the ground. You have thrown the ball upward with the speed $v$ then the initial energy
$$E_i=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+mgh$$
As the ball moves upward, its speed gets down and the height from the ground will increase (so the potential energy) so that at any time $t$ we have
$$E(t)=\frac{1}{2}mv'^2+mg(h+y)$$
Using the equation of motion
$$v'=v-gt$$
and $$y=vt-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$$
$$E(t)=\frac{1}{2}m(v-gt)^2+mg(h+vt-\frac{1}{2}gt^2)$$
solving this will leads to
$$E(t)=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+mgh=E_i$$
This is what we meant by energy conservation. :)

Comment: So the kinetic energy given to the ball by the person is being converted to potential energy .

Comment: Unlike when  a ball falls due to gravity where potential energy of the ball  is converted to kinetic energy

Comment: Exactly, you are right.

Comment: What would happen if the instantaneous velocity kept increasing ?

Comment: And How this supposed to be happening?

Comment: By putting a lot of force on the ball ?

Comment: Then the work done by the force appears as the kinetic energy of the particle.